# How to allow replacement of existing methods at link time with Xcode? Using 'ar -r' instead of libtool?

Tags: c++, xcode, g++, xcodebuild, libtool-xcode

We have some code that compile fine on Mac OS X with g++ using makefiles, but I cannot build successfully with Xcode.

Here is the brief overview of the project setup, there are instances of the following:

1. libA.a

   - contains myclass_stub.cpp which implements func()
   - Our makefiles would package the library with 'ar -r', which allows replacement of existing methods.
   - Xcode would use libtool to package it
2. program.exe
   contains myclass.cpp which implements func() as well.
   and links libA.a statically using g++

If I were to build libA.a and program.exe with Xcode, it complains about "Duplicate symbol" func in myclass_stub.o and myclass.o at link time.

I also tried compiling program.exe with Xcode, and linking it against libA.a that was packaged with 'ar -r', but it stills complains about duplicate symbol.

Having duplicate implementation might not be ideal, but I cannot get around it at the moment. If I could get the code to build with makefiles using standard 'ar' and 'g++', I would like to know what options I need to set in Xcode for it to work.

Now, my questions:

1. I would like to use 'ar -r' to package the library in Xcode instead. Is it possible? If so, how? Is there a similar option with libtool where I can force replacement of existing symbols?
2. I suppose the difference between libtool and 'ar -r' might not be the main difference between building with Xcode and with makefiles. I do have the same compiler flags, but the list of input/object files is mostly likely in a different order. Do you see any other possible solutions to this linking error?

I saw a related to question @
[libtool vs ar for creating a static library (xcode linker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591384/libtool-vs-ar-for-creating-a-static-library-xcode-linker),  but not the solution

By the way, I also tried adding all-load and --force-load, but they don't seem to do much since I am just trying to build for x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about xcode, but have you thought about using weak symbols (in g++ : **attribute**((weak))) for symbols that should be overridden ?